# ETW logging in UWP

Tags: uwp, etw

I would like to use ETW for event logging, and believe I have everything setup correctly. However, I don't see any events in the file when the app quits. I have a FileLoggingSession and LoggingChannel created and associated. I don't get any errors when I use LoggingChannel. Everything seems to behave properly, but the log files don't appear to have any of the messages I post.

```
    public EtwLogger()
    {
        _channel = new LoggingChannel(LibSettings._etwLogChannel, null);
        _channel.LoggingEnabled += _channel_LoggingEnabled;
        _session = new FileLoggingSession(LibSettings._etwLogSession);
        _session.LogFileGenerated += _session_LogFileGenerated;
        _session.AddLoggingChannel(_channel);
    }
    public Task Log(LogEntry logEntry)
    {
        if (!isDisposed && _channel.IsEnabled(SeverityToLoggingLevel(logEntry.Severity)))
        {
            string message = $"{logEntry.TimeStamp.ToLocalTime().ToString("s")} {SeverityToString(logEntry.Severity)} : ";
            if (logEntry.Source?.Length > 0)
                message += $"{logEntry.Source} {logEntry.Message}";
            else
                message += $"{logEntry.Message}";
            _channel.LogMessage(message, SeverityToLoggingLevel(logEntry.Severity));
            Debug.WriteLine($"ETW: {message}");
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

Comment: I assume you're not using your own custom ETW manifest? What provider are you recording?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. I do not have a custom manifest, but not sure about your question on the provider. Basically, I just want to log event messages using the ETW framework. I used the UWP sample app for most of this code. I just don't see the .LogMessage(...) calls showing in the .etl file. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. It is working, I just need to trap the program close and issue the .CloseAndSaveToFileAsync()

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. I need to issue the `.CloseAndSaveToFileAsync()` when the program terminates (or suspends).

Comment: To be more succinct, i added a suspend handler and called a method on the logger that called .CloseAndSaveToFileAsync(). Then I renamed the last file to my "standard" log file convention.